# How to create permissions for excel file using pandas read_excel method?

Tags: python-3.x, file-permissions, user-permissions

I just wanted to create permisssions and used the below code:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
      df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
os.chmod("output.xlsx", 0o777)
```

But It was not working

And I am interested in using `pandas.read_excel()` method to create permisssion when i create Excel files.

or Is it possible to create any other way ??

Comment: Can you be more explicit? what exactly do you want to achieve? what did you try and how did it work?

Comment: HI @MohamedNidabdella I hope this helps. I just edited it.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to create permissions using `read_excel` from `pandas`. 
In the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html it is clear that `read_excel` only use is to read an excel file and convert it to a `pandas` DataFrame

Comment: You use `read_excel` to read an excel file, `to_excel` is what is used to create Excel file from `DataFrame` but it doesn't have any parameter or workaround to add permissions.

Comment: else how can i add persmissions for excel files??

Comment: `os.chmod` is the best solution